# IBM API Connect v 2018 installation issues

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, administration, apiconnect

Hope we can see that there is lot of changes in installation steps for installing API Connect with version 2018 deploying using ova files

Here is what i did for installing management console following ibm help link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMNED_2018/com.ibm.apic.install.doc/overview_installing_mgmtvm_apimgmt.html

1. Generation of config ISO file for the management server skipping optional default password setting in iso file
2. Deploying of ova file to VM
3. uploading the iso file to data-source of vm

while starting the vm, I can see the my hostname setted but, unable to login to management console.

tried with password !n0r1t5@C & 7iron-hide, but no luck. Could someone help me out!

Thx 
Srikanth

Answer (score 0):

I have had many happy hours struggling with the ova installation of APIC 2018.

As you skipped setting a default (hashed) password for user `apicadm` then you will not be able to log in using the CLI. Follow the instructions in step 9.h to create the hashed password on your system, and include it in the yaml file.

A few things to note:

- If using Windows, make sure you use `mkisofs.exe` from the CDRTools package.
- Double check that the three sections with config values in the iso file, actually have some values
- The iso file must be kept connected to the VM - even though it has been configured.

Have you tried logging in using SSH? That will allow you to check that apic is running courtesy of `sudo apic status`